# Change properties of rose plot

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-figure, axis, rose-plot

I use the function rose2 in my script in order to plot a rose plot. I am working with Matlab 2016a and thus still use the  rose function. I use rose2 in order to be able to set the maximum value for the r axis and fill the triangles.
I use "findall" in order to rotate the location of the R-axis labels.
This works very well:

```
maxHistogramValue = 100;

f=figure;

clf

% Set the max value to maxHistogramValue:

polar(0, maxHistogramValue,'-k')

% Set the location of the R-axis labels in degrees.
% Extract all of the 'Text' objects from the polar plot.
ax = findall(f.Children, 'Type', 'Axes');
% Filter the 'Text' objects by the 'HorizontalAlignment' property.
% PLEASE NOTE: This may not generalize to other versions of MATLAB
% where the default 'HorizontalAlignment' value for R-axis labels is not
% set to 'left'.
labels = findall(ax, 'Type', 'Text', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'left');
% Set the degrees of the R-axis Labels.
degrees = 285;
% Update the position of each R-axis label.
for label = labels'
    currentX = label.Position(1);
    currentY = label.Position(2);
    radius = sqrt(currentX^2 + currentY^2);
    newX = cos(degtorad(degrees)) * radius;
    newY = sin(degtorad(degrees)) * radius;
    label.Position = [newX, newY];
end

hold on;

% Now use rose2:

rose2(inp, theta_rad)

%make transparent
alpha(0.5)

view(-90,90)
```

[image: rose plot]

And I figured out how to change the font size with:

```
labels = findall(ax, 'Type', 'Text');
for label = labels'
    label.FontSize = 16;
end
```

But I want to display the angles with the degree symbol.
I tried to add it to the loop, but first, weired numbers are displayed and second, it also changes the r Axis, which I dont want of course.

```
labels = findall(ax, 'Type', 'Text');
for label = labels'
    label.FontSize = 16;
    label.String=label.String+char(176);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `labels` you will see that it contains more labels. You only want to modify `labels(1:12)`:

```
labels = findall(ax, 'Type', 'Text');
for label = labels(1:12)'
    label.String=[label.String char(176)];
end
```

Also, your `label.String=label.String+char(176);` is not matlab syntax.